# Splitting Field and Irreducibility

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $f(x) = x^3 − x + 1 ∈ F_3[x]$. I wish to show that $[L : F_3] = 3$ where $L$ is the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F_3$. First, I can show $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F_3$ right since it has no roots there. Then, I am not sure~

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha$ is a root, then $\alpha+1$ and $\alpha-1$ are roots, too (easy to check); so $L=K[\alpha]$. Hence, $[L:\mathbb F_3]=3$.

Comment: Ah I see but sorry how do i check the roots part explicitly? Perhaps I am not seeing it as I am confused what is in $F_3$

Comment: @Homaniac In characteristic three you have $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3$. In particular: $(\alpha+1)^3=\alpha^3+1^3$. This will let you check the claim about other roots. Another explanation comes from Galois theory (of finite fields). Have you covered that yet?

Comment: $F_3$ can be thought of as the set $\{\,0,1,2\,\}$ with addition and multiplication modulo 3.

Comment: It also helps to notice that $f(x)=(x-1)x(x+1)+1$.

Comment: How do I show f is irreducible in $F_3$ or is it just obvious from the factorization?

Comment: Ah okay I can just sub 0,1,2 and see that none gives 0~

Comment: How does L=K[a] follow from the roots though? Why need to introduce K?

Comment: $K$ is just the notation ajotatxe is using for $F_3$.